# Why are my attempts to burn TAILS failing?

Tags: tails

I attempt to burn the TAILS disk like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]
The result on the disk is this:
[image]
and all attempts to boot TAILS fail. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but you did try to boot from CD, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Click 'verify disc after burning'. What does happen now?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your download is not corrupt,
I would reccommend that you try to use use ImgBurn instead of windows dvd burning software. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImgBurn , it's a free tool that burns almost any kind of formats to cd\DVD.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out to be my BIOS settings. The computer went to its pre-loaded OS first. I knew to change them, but I was accidently accessing the startup settings for my default operating system rather than the actual BIOS settings. For anyone who is encountering a similar problem, you should hit the button that takes you to your settings when you see the name of the company that makes the computer, when you see the OS it is too late.